# Contact form 7 Checkbox and title acceptence

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

maybe someone has an idea how I can align the label of acceptance in case there are two lines. Is it possible to align the label left according to the first line? At the moment it looks like this:

[Contact form with field acceptance](http://www.naxos-apartments.de/en/kontakt/)

Hope you understand what I mean, and thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Add this snippet in your css:

```
.acceptance-656 label {
    display: flex;
}
.acceptance-656 input {
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
}
```